# Which distribution integrates well with a sum of random variables raised to a power?

Tags: distributions, expected-value

Imagine I have three random variables $x$, $y$ and $z$, and I have a function of these three random variables $f(x,y,z;a,b,c)=(xa+yb+zc)^{\alpha}$, for $\alpha>0$. The random variables are non-negative, $x,y,z\geq0$. The parameters $a,b$ and $c$ are just non-random, non-negative scalars.

Is there any distribution that can give me a closed form solution for the expectation of $f(x,y,z)$, i.e $\mathbb{E}(f(x,y,z))$?

With

$$ \mathbb{E}(f(x,y,z)) = \int_{x}\int_{y}\int_{z}(xa+yb+zc)^{\alpha}dF(x,y,z) $$

I am interested in particular, for distributions that allow correlations between $x$, $y$ and $z$, but all suggestions are appreciated.

A feature I would like to preserve is that the result is still a sum of the the constants $a$, $b$ and $c$, raised to some power.

My problem, is a problem in economics. This function is a type of CES function and I am looking for a distribution that would integrate it nicely. The idea is that this expectation is nested in a maximization problem in which I choose $a,b$ and $c$.

Thanks so much

Comment: There are a huge number.  The first thing to consider is what the support of these distributions is intended to be, because that imposes a strong constraint on the solutions.  (For instance, when $F$ is supported on a bounded set that stays away from the origin, then you can make $\mathrm{d}F$ proportional to $(x+y+z)^{-\alpha}.$)  Could you provide more information, then, about the statistical or machine learning problem you are trying to address?

Comment: I made some edits. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @whuber Do you think the question requires further clarification?

Comment: I am confused by the remark at the end. The integral explicitly is a function only of $\alpha:$ that is, for any number $\alpha$ the integral is a number. In what possible sense, then, could it be a "sum of random variables, raised to some power"?

Comment: I see what you are saying, I just edited the question again. What I meant to say is that a solution based in making the dF proportional to $(x+y+z)^{-\alpha}$ might not be ideal, because I want the $\alpha$ to play a role.

Comment: @whuber is this clear now?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want $F$ not to depend on $\alpha$?  That is, for any $\alpha$ (within some defined range, anyway) the solution will have a simple form? I am completely baffled still by your remark about "sum of random variables:" that just makes no sense for this problem.

Comment: @whuber I did a further edit. I think now it should be clear. SOrry for the confusion!

Comment: @whuber now, I am thinking that what I need is a distribution that is closed under addition so that the thing inside the parenthesis has a known distribution and that has some distribution when taken to the power.

Comment: I don't think that would work.  What looks more promising is to define distributions that are separable in spherical coordinates $(\rho, \Omega),$ so that $\mathrm{d}F$ can be expressed as a product $f_1(\rho)f_2(\Omega).$ You might need to expand $f_2$ in spherical harmonics. I find it instructive to work on the 2D analog of your problem for insight.

Comment: which family of distributions has that property?

Comment: To what does "that property" refer? If you mean separability, that is determined by all measurable functions $f_1$ for which $\int_0^\infty r^2f_1(r)\mathrm{d}r=1$ and *any* probability measure $f_2$ on the positive octant of the sphere $S^2.$ Since you can rescale $(a,b,c)$ with an obvious and simple effect on the integral, $F$ might as well be radially symmetric, so you lose almost no generality with this approach.